# Auto-loading of org file into org-mode broken

Tags: org-mode

I have re-organized my Lisp sub-folders and files. However, I discovered afterwards that org-mode does not work anymore. This was working fine before I moved files and folders around. I have not deleted any file or folder.

So when I initially open an org file, it enters the debugger and shows this error:

```
(file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "org")
```

How do I fix this? How do I determine which directory it is looking for "org" and how do I set it?

My init.el file has the following lines, if it could help answer the above questions:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "E:/Lisp/slime-2.20")
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.cl\\'" . lisp-mode)) 
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.org\\'" . org-mode))
```

Files with extension .cl seems to works fine, but those with .org do not open in org-mode. The last line in my init.el file is:

```
(setq default-directory "E:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/quicklisp/local-projects/")
```

It is also possible that this is caused by something other than changes in files/folders.

**Edit:**

So this is the backtrace (really long!)

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-error "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "org")
  org-mode()
  set-auto-mode-0(org-mode nil)
  set-auto-mode()
  normal-mode(t)
  after-find-file(nil t)
  find-file-noselect-1(#<buffer CCLReference.org> "~/quicklisp/local-projects/CCLReference.org" nil nil "~/quicklisp/local-projects/CCLReference.org" (281474977139625 2696378950))
  find-file-noselect("e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/quicklisp/local-projects/CCLReference.org" nil nil nil)
  (let ((b (find-file-noselect file-name nil nil nil))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer b) (rename-buffer (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp buf) (>= ... 9) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-buf-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-buf) buf))) (aref buf 2)) t) (wg-set-buffer-uid-or-error (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp buf) (>= ... 9) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-buf-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-buf) buf))) (aref buf 1))) (if wg-restore-mark (progn (set-mark (progn nil (or (progn nil ...) (signal ... ...)) (aref buf 5))) (deactivate-mark))) (wg-deserialize-buffer-local-variables buf)) (if switch (switch-to-buffer b)) b)
  (condition-case err (let ((b (find-file-noselect file-name nil nil nil))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer b) (rename-buffer (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... buf))) (aref buf 2)) t) (wg-set-buffer-uid-or-error (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... buf))) (aref buf 1))) (if wg-restore-mark (progn (set-mark (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref buf 5))) (deactivate-mark))) (wg-deserialize-buffer-local-variables buf)) (if switch (switch-to-buffer b)) b) (error (message "Error while restoring a file %s:\n  %s" file-name (error-message-string err)) nil))
  (cond ((file-exists-p file-name) (condition-case err (let ((b (find-file-noselect file-name nil nil nil))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer b) (rename-buffer (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref buf 2)) t) (wg-set-buffer-uid-or-error (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref buf 1))) (if wg-restore-mark (progn (set-mark ...) (deactivate-mark))) (wg-deserialize-buffer-local-variables buf)) (if switch (switch-to-buffer b)) b) (error (message "Error while restoring a file %s:\n  %s" file-name (error-message-string err)) nil))) (t (if (file-directory-p (file-name-directory file-name)) (dired (file-name-directory file-name)) (progn (message "Attempt to restore nonexistent file: %S" file-name) nil))))
  (progn (cond ((file-exists-p file-name) (condition-case err (let ((b (find-file-noselect file-name nil nil nil))) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer b) (rename-buffer (progn nil ... ...) t) (wg-set-buffer-uid-or-error (progn nil ... ...)) (if wg-restore-mark (progn ... ...)) (wg-deserialize-buffer-local-variables buf)) (if switch (switch-to-buffer b)) b) (error (message "Error while restoring a file %s:\n  %s" file-name (error-message-string err)) nil))) (t (if (file-directory-p (file-name-directory file-name)) (dired (file-name-directory file-name)) (progn (message "Attempt to restore nonexistent file: %S" file-name) nil)))))
  (if (and file-name (or wg-restore-remote-buffers (not (file-remote-p file-name)))) (progn (cond ((file-exists-p file-name) (condition-case err (let ((b ...)) (save-current-buffer (set-buffer b) (rename-buffer ... t) (wg-set-buffer-uid-or-error ...) (if wg-restore-mark ...) (wg-deserialize-buffer-local-variables buf)) (if switch (switch-to-buffer b)) b) (error (message "Error while restoring a file %s:\n  %s" file-name (error-message-string err)) nil))) (t (if (file-directory-p (file-name-directory file-name)) (dired (file-name-directory file-name)) (progn (message "Attempt to restore nonexistent file: %S" file-name) nil))))))
  (let ((file-name (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp buf) (>= ... 9) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-buf-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-buf) buf))) (aref buf 3)))) (if (and file-name (or wg-restore-remote-buffers (not (file-remote-p file-name)))) (progn (cond ((file-exists-p file-name) (condition-case err (let (...) (save-current-buffer ... ... ... ... ...) (if switch ...) b) (error (message "Error while restoring a file %s:\n  %s" file-name ...) nil))) (t (if (file-directory-p (file-name-directory file-name)) (dired (file-name-directory file-name)) (progn (message "Attempt to restore nonexistent file: %S" file-name) nil)))))))
  wg-restore-file-buffer([cl-struct-wg-buf "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST" "CCLReference.org" "e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/quicklisp/local-projects/CCLReference.org" 526 526 ((major-mode . fundamental-mode) nil nil nil nil nil nil nil) nil nil] t)
  (or (wg-restore-existing-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-special-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-file-buffer buf switch) (progn (wg-restore-default-buffer switch) nil))
  (prog1 (or (wg-restore-existing-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-special-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-file-buffer buf switch) (progn (wg-restore-default-buffer switch) nil)) (if wg-mess-with-buffer-list (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-function)))
  (progn (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-original) (prog1 (or (wg-restore-existing-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-special-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-file-buffer buf switch) (progn (wg-restore-default-buffer switch) nil)) (if wg-mess-with-buffer-list (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-function))))
  (if buf (progn (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-original) (prog1 (or (wg-restore-existing-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-special-buffer buf switch) (wg-restore-file-buffer buf switch) (progn (wg-restore-default-buffer switch) nil)) (if wg-mess-with-buffer-list (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-function)))))
  wg-restore-buffer([cl-struct-wg-buf "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST" "CCLReference.org" "e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/quicklisp/local-projects/CCLReference.org" 526 526 ((major-mode . fundamental-mode) nil nil nil nil nil nil nil) nil nil] t)
  (if (wg-restore-buffer buf t) (progn (let ((window (or selwin (selected-window)))) (let* ((G212 win) (win-point (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref G212 4))) (win-start (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref G212 5))) (win-hscroll (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref G212 6)))) (set-window-start window win-start t) (set-window-hscroll window win-hscroll) (set-window-point window (cond ((not wg-restore-point) win-start) ((eq win-point :max) (point-max)) (t win-point))) (if (>= win-start (point-max)) (progn (recenter))))) (if wg-restore-window-dedicated-p (progn (set-window-dedicated-p selwin (progn nil (or (progn nil ...) (signal ... ...)) (aref win 7)))))))
  (if (not buf) (wg-restore-default-buffer) (if (wg-restore-buffer buf t) (progn (let ((window (or selwin (selected-window)))) (let* ((G212 win) (win-point (progn nil ... ...)) (win-start (progn nil ... ...)) (win-hscroll (progn nil ... ...))) (set-window-start window win-start t) (set-window-hscroll window win-hscroll) (set-window-point window (cond (... win-start) (... ...) (t win-point))) (if (>= win-start (point-max)) (progn (recenter))))) (if wg-restore-window-dedicated-p (progn (set-window-dedicated-p selwin (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref win 7))))))))
  (let ((selwin (selected-window)) (buf (wg-find-buf-by-uid (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... win))) (aref win 10))))) (if (not buf) (wg-restore-default-buffer) (if (wg-restore-buffer buf t) (progn (let ((window (or selwin ...))) (let* ((G212 win) (win-point ...) (win-start ...) (win-hscroll ...)) (set-window-start window win-start t) (set-window-hscroll window win-hscroll) (set-window-point window (cond ... ... ...)) (if (>= win-start ...) (progn ...)))) (if wg-restore-window-dedicated-p (progn (set-window-dedicated-p selwin (progn nil ... ...))))))) (condition-case nil (progn (set-window-prev-buffers selwin (wg-unpickel (wg-win-parameter win (quote prev-buffers)))) (set-window-next-buffers selwin (wg-unpickel (wg-win-parameter win (quote next-buffers))))) (error nil)))
  wg-restore-window([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 81 19) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"])
  (if (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= (length w) 5) (memq (aref w 0) cl-struct-wg-wtree-tags) t)) (let* ((dir (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... w))) (aref w 2))) (--cl-var-- (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... w))) (aref w 4))) (rest nil) (win nil)) (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq rest --cl-var-- win (car-safe (prog1 rest (setq rest (cdr rest))))) (if rest (progn (split-window nil (wg-w-size win dir) (not dir)))) (wg-restore-window-tree-helper win) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil) (wg-restore-window w) (if (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= (length w) 11) (memq (aref w 0) cl-struct-wg-win-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-win) w))) (aref w 8)) (progn (setq wg-window-tree-selected-window (selected-window)))) (if (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= (length w) 11) (memq (aref w 0) cl-struct-wg-win-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-win) w))) (aref w 9)) (progn (setq minibuffer-scroll-window (selected-window)))) (other-window 1))
  wg-restore-window-tree-helper([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 81 19) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"])
  (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq rest --cl-var-- win (car-safe (prog1 rest (setq rest (cdr rest))))) (if rest (progn (split-window nil (wg-w-size win dir) (not dir)))) (wg-restore-window-tree-helper win) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--)))
  (let* ((dir (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= ... 5) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-wtree-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-wtree) w))) (aref w 2))) (--cl-var-- (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= ... 5) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-wtree-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-wtree) w))) (aref w 4))) (rest nil) (win nil)) (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq rest --cl-var-- win (car-safe (prog1 rest (setq rest (cdr rest))))) (if rest (progn (split-window nil (wg-w-size win dir) (not dir)))) (wg-restore-window-tree-helper win) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil)
  (if (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= (length w) 5) (memq (aref w 0) cl-struct-wg-wtree-tags) t)) (let* ((dir (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... w))) (aref w 2))) (--cl-var-- (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... w))) (aref w 4))) (rest nil) (win nil)) (while (consp --cl-var--) (setq rest --cl-var-- win (car-safe (prog1 rest (setq rest (cdr rest))))) (if rest (progn (split-window nil (wg-w-size win dir) (not dir)))) (wg-restore-window-tree-helper win) (setq --cl-var-- (cdr --cl-var--))) nil) (wg-restore-window w) (if (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= (length w) 11) (memq (aref w 0) cl-struct-wg-win-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-win) w))) (aref w 8)) (progn (setq wg-window-tree-selected-window (selected-window)))) (if (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp w) (>= (length w) 11) (memq (aref w 0) cl-struct-wg-win-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-win) w))) (aref w 9)) (progn (setq minibuffer-scroll-window (selected-window)))) (other-window 1))
  wg-restore-window-tree-helper([cl-struct-wg-wtree nil t (0 2 81 37) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 81 19) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"] [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil nil (0 19 81 37) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 19 38 37) :max 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QT5F8KRCUYO-5R34Q"] [cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (38 19 81 37) 1 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QXS11GHH5A8-5Q4FF"])])])
  (let ((window-min-width wg-window-min-width) (window-min-height wg-window-min-height) (wg-window-tree-selected-window nil)) (wg-reset-window-tree) (wg-restore-window-tree-helper wtree) (let ((it wg-window-tree-selected-window)) (if it (progn (select-window it)))))
  wg-restore-window-tree([cl-struct-wg-wtree nil t (0 2 81 37) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 81 19) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"] [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil nil (0 19 81 37) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 19 38 37) :max 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QT5F8KRCUYO-5R34Q"] [cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (38 19 81 37) 1 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QXS11GHH5A8-5Q4FF"])])])
  (let ((wg-record-incorrectly-restored-bufs t) (wg-incorrectly-restored-bufs nil) (params (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp wconfig) (>= ... 11) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-wconfig-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-wconfig) wconfig))) (aref wconfig 3))) fullscreen) (wg-barf-on-active-minibuffer) (if wg-restore-scroll-bars (progn (wg-wconfig-restore-scroll-bars wconfig))) (if (null (wg-current-workgroup t)) (progn (set-frame-parameter frame (quote fullscreen) (if (assoc (quote fullscreen) params) (cdr (assoc (quote fullscreen) params)) nil)))) (if (and wg-restore-frame-position (not (frame-parameter nil (quote fullscreen))) (null (wg-current-workgroup t))) (progn (wg-wconfig-restore-frame-position wconfig frame))) (wg-restore-window-tree (wg-scale-wconfig-to-frame wconfig)) (if wg-incorrectly-restored-bufs (progn (message "Unable to restore these buffers: %SIf you want, restore them manually and try again." (mapcar (quote wg-buf-name) wg-incorrectly-restored-bufs)))))
  wg-restore-wconfig([cl-struct-wg-wconfig "0HX40R2D3DJD6FHC-7OTTK" nil ((fullscreen)) 1720 0 185 58 right 21 [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil t (0 2 189 59) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 189 30) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"] [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil nil (0 30 189 59) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 30 90 59) :max 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QT5F8KRCUYO-5R34Q"] [cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (90 30 189 59) 1 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QXS11GHH5A8-5Q4FF"])])]])
  wg-restore-wconfig-undoably([cl-struct-wg-wconfig "0HX40R2D3DJD6FHC-7OTTK" nil ((fullscreen)) 1720 0 185 58 right 21 [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil t (0 2 189 59) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 189 30) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"] [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil nil (0 30 189 59) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 30 90 59) :max 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QT5F8KRCUYO-5R34Q"] [cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (90 30 189 59) 1 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QXS11GHH5A8-5Q4FF"])])]] t)
  (let (wg-flag-modified) (wg-restore-wconfig-undoably (wg-workgroup-working-wconfig workgroup) t))
  wg-restore-workgroup([cl-struct-wg-workgroup "0HWK0Y14D7CHH5A8-5ABE3" "First workgroup" t nil [cl-struct-wg-wconfig "0HX40R2D3DJD6FHC-7OTTK" nil ((fullscreen)) 1720 0 185 58 right 21 [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil t (0 2 189 59) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 2 189 30) 1 1 0 nil t nil "0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST"] [cl-struct-wg-wtree nil nil (0 30 189 59) ([cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (0 30 90 59) :max 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QT5F8KRCUYO-5R34Q"] [cl-struct-wg-win nil nil (90 30 189 59) 1 1 0 nil nil nil "0HX40QXS11GHH5A8-5Q4FF"])])]] nil nil nil ("0HX40QZQF4Q96FHC-7IJST")])
  (progn (run-hooks (quote wg-before-switch-to-workgroup-hook)) (let (wg-flag-modified) (wg-set-workgroup-parameter (quote ecb) (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) ecb-minor-mode))) (if (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) (boundp (quote ecb-frame)) (fboundp (quote ecb-deactivate)) ecb-minor-mode (equal ecb-frame (selected-frame))) (let ((ecb-split-edit-window-after-start (quote before-deactivation))) (ecb-deactivate))) (wg-restore-workgroup workgroup) (wg-set-previous-workgroup current) (wg-set-current-workgroup workgroup) (let (wg-flag-modified) (let ((it (wg-current-workgroup t))) (if it (progn (wg-set-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup) (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref it 2)))))) (let ((it (wg-previous-workgroup t))) (if it (progn (wg-set-session-parameter (quote prev-workgroup) (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref it 2))))))) (if (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) (not ecb-minor-mode) (fboundp (quote ecb-activate)) (wg-workgroup-parameter (wg-current-workgroup t) (quote ecb) nil)) (let ((ecb-split-edit-window-after-start (quote before-deactivation))) (ecb-activate))) (let* ((buffers (mapcar (quote window-buffer) (window-list))) (buffer-names (mapcar (quote buffer-name) buffers))) (if (and (featurep (quote sr-speedbar)) (member sr-speedbar-buffer-name buffer-names)) (progn (setq sr-speedbar-window (get-buffer-window sr-speedbar-buffer-name))))) (if wg-mess-with-buffer-list (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-function)) (wg-message (concat (wg-add-face :cmd "Switched: ") (let ((cl-x (wg-current-workgroup t))) (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... cl-x))) (aref cl-x 2))))) (run-hooks (quote wg-after-switch-to-workgroup-hook)))
  (unwind-protect (progn (run-hooks (quote wg-before-switch-to-workgroup-hook)) (let (wg-flag-modified) (wg-set-workgroup-parameter (quote ecb) (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) ecb-minor-mode))) (if (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) (boundp (quote ecb-frame)) (fboundp (quote ecb-deactivate)) ecb-minor-mode (equal ecb-frame (selected-frame))) (let ((ecb-split-edit-window-after-start (quote before-deactivation))) (ecb-deactivate))) (wg-restore-workgroup workgroup) (wg-set-previous-workgroup current) (wg-set-current-workgroup workgroup) (let (wg-flag-modified) (let ((it (wg-current-workgroup t))) (if it (progn (wg-set-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup) (progn nil ... ...))))) (let ((it (wg-previous-workgroup t))) (if it (progn (wg-set-session-parameter (quote prev-workgroup) (progn nil ... ...)))))) (if (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) (not ecb-minor-mode) (fboundp (quote ecb-activate)) (wg-workgroup-parameter (wg-current-workgroup t) (quote ecb) nil)) (let ((ecb-split-edit-window-after-start (quote before-deactivation))) (ecb-activate))) (let* ((buffers (mapcar (quote window-buffer) (window-list))) (buffer-names (mapcar (quote buffer-name) buffers))) (if (and (featurep (quote sr-speedbar)) (member sr-speedbar-buffer-name buffer-names)) (progn (setq sr-speedbar-window (get-buffer-window sr-speedbar-buffer-name))))) (if wg-mess-with-buffer-list (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-function)) (wg-message (concat (wg-add-face :cmd "Switched: ") (let ((cl-x (wg-current-workgroup t))) (progn nil (or (progn nil ...) (signal ... ...)) (aref cl-x 2))))) (run-hooks (quote wg-after-switch-to-workgroup-hook))) (if current (progn (car-safe (prog1 wg-deactivation-list (setq wg-deactivation-list (cdr wg-deactivation-list)))))))
  (let ((workgroup (wg-get-workgroup-create workgroup)) (current (wg-current-workgroup t))) (if (and (eq workgroup current) (not noerror)) (progn (error "Already on: %s" (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... current))) (aref current 2))))) (if current (progn (setq wg-deactivation-list (cons current wg-deactivation-list)))) (unwind-protect (progn (run-hooks (quote wg-before-switch-to-workgroup-hook)) (let (wg-flag-modified) (wg-set-workgroup-parameter (quote ecb) (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) ecb-minor-mode))) (if (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) (boundp (quote ecb-frame)) (fboundp (quote ecb-deactivate)) ecb-minor-mode (equal ecb-frame (selected-frame))) (let ((ecb-split-edit-window-after-start (quote before-deactivation))) (ecb-deactivate))) (wg-restore-workgroup workgroup) (wg-set-previous-workgroup current) (wg-set-current-workgroup workgroup) (let (wg-flag-modified) (let ((it (wg-current-workgroup t))) (if it (progn (wg-set-session-parameter ... ...)))) (let ((it (wg-previous-workgroup t))) (if it (progn (wg-set-session-parameter ... ...))))) (if (and (boundp (quote ecb-minor-mode)) (not ecb-minor-mode) (fboundp (quote ecb-activate)) (wg-workgroup-parameter (wg-current-workgroup t) (quote ecb) nil)) (let ((ecb-split-edit-window-after-start (quote before-deactivation))) (ecb-activate))) (let* ((buffers (mapcar (quote window-buffer) (window-list))) (buffer-names (mapcar (quote buffer-name) buffers))) (if (and (featurep (quote sr-speedbar)) (member sr-speedbar-buffer-name buffer-names)) (progn (setq sr-speedbar-window (get-buffer-window sr-speedbar-buffer-name))))) (if wg-mess-with-buffer-list (fset (quote buffer-list) wg-buffer-list-function)) (wg-message (concat (wg-add-face :cmd "Switched: ") (let ((cl-x ...)) (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref cl-x 2))))) (run-hooks (quote wg-after-switch-to-workgroup-hook))) (if current (progn (car-safe (prog1 wg-deactivation-list (setq wg-deactivation-list (cdr wg-deactivation-list))))))))
  wg-switch-to-workgroup("First workgroup")
  (if (and wg-load-last-workgroup (member (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup)) (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (car it)))
  (if (and wg-open-this-wg (member wg-open-this-wg (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup wg-open-this-wg) (if (and wg-load-last-workgroup (member (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup)) (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (car it))))
  (progn (if (and wg-open-this-wg (member wg-open-this-wg (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup wg-open-this-wg) (if (and wg-load-last-workgroup (member (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup)) (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (car it)))) (let ((it (wg-session-parameter (quote prev-workgroup)))) (if it (progn (if (and (member it (wg-workgroup-names)) (wg-get-workgroup it t)) (progn (wg-set-previous-workgroup (wg-get-workgroup it t))))))))
  (if it (progn (if (and wg-open-this-wg (member wg-open-this-wg (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup wg-open-this-wg) (if (and wg-load-last-workgroup (member (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup)) (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (car it)))) (let ((it (wg-session-parameter (quote prev-workgroup)))) (if it (progn (if (and (member it ...) (wg-get-workgroup it t)) (progn (wg-set-previous-workgroup ...))))))))
  (let ((it (let ((cl-x (wg-current-session))) (progn nil (or (progn nil (and ... ... ... t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list ... cl-x))) (aref cl-x 7))))) (if it (progn (if (and wg-open-this-wg (member wg-open-this-wg (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup wg-open-this-wg) (if (and wg-load-last-workgroup (member (wg-session-parameter ...) (wg-workgroup-names))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (wg-session-parameter (quote last-workgroup))) (wg-switch-to-workgroup (car it)))) (let ((it (wg-session-parameter (quote prev-workgroup)))) (if it (progn (if (and ... ...) (progn ...))))))))
  (cond ((file-exists-p filename) (let ((session (read (f-read-text filename)))) (if (progn nil (and (vectorp session) (>= (length session) 9) (memq (aref session 0) cl-struct-wg-session-tags) t)) nil (error "%S is not a Workgroups session file." filename)) (progn nil (or (progn nil (and (vectorp session) (>= ... 9) (memq ... cl-struct-wg-session-tags) t)) (signal (quote wrong-type-argument) (list (quote wg-session) session))) (let* ((v session)) (aset v 5 filename))) (wg-reset-internal (wg-unpickel-session-parameters session))) (if wg-control-frames (wg-restore-frames)) (let ((it (let ((cl-x ...)) (progn nil (or ... ...) (aref cl-x 7))))) (if it (progn (if (and wg-open-this-wg (member wg-open-this-wg ...)) (wg-switch-to-workgroup wg-open-this-wg) (if (and wg-load-last-workgroup ...) (wg-switch-to-workgroup ...) (wg-switch-to-workgroup ...))) (let ((it ...)) (if it (progn ...)))))) (wg-message (concat (wg-add-face :cmd "Loaded: ") (wg-add-face :file filename))) (wg-mark-everything-unmodified)) (t (wg-query-and-save-if-modified) (wg-reset-internal (wg-make-session :file-name filename)) (wg-message (concat (wg-add-face :cmd "(New Workgroups session file)")))))
  wg-open-session("~/.emacs_workgroups")
  (condition-case err (wg-open-session wg-session-file) (error (message "Error finding `wg-session-file': %s" err)))
  (progn (condition-case err (wg-open-session wg-session-file) (error (message "Error finding `wg-session-file': %s" err))))
  (if (and wg-session-load-on-start (file-exists-p wg-session-file)) (progn (condition-case err (wg-open-session wg-session-file) (error (message "Error finding `wg-session-file': %s" err)))))
  (cond (workgroups-mode (if (boundp (quote desktop-restore-frames)) (setq desktop-restore-frames nil)) (wg-reset-internal) (wg-add-workgroups-mode-minor-mode-entries) (wg-enable-all-advice) (wg-add-or-remove-workgroups-hooks nil) (wg-change-modeline) (if (featurep (quote sr-speedbar)) (progn (ad-disable-advice (quote delete-other-windows) (quote around) (quote sr-speedbar-delete-other-window-advice)) (ad-disable-advice (quote delete-window) (quote before) (quote sr-speedbar-delete-window-advice)))) (if (and wg-session-load-on-start (file-exists-p wg-session-file)) (progn (condition-case err (wg-open-session wg-session-file) (error (message "Error finding `wg-session-file': %s" err))))) (run-hooks (quote workgroups-mode-hook))) (t (wg-save-session-on-workgroups-mode-exit) (wg-disable-all-advice) (wg-add-or-remove-workgroups-hooks t) (wg-remove-mode-line-display) (run-hooks (quote workgroups-mode-exit-hook))))
  workgroups-mode(1)
  eval-buffer(#<buffer  *load*> nil "e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 30822
  load-with-code-conversion("e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/.emacs.d/init.el" "e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("e:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[0 "\205\266
```

Yes, I am running the built-in org-mode. My emacs is version is  "25.3.1 (x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2017-09-18".

When I added these load-paths to the init.el file, it doesn't enter the debugger anymore and now opens in org-mode:

```
(add-to-list 'load-path "E:/Lisp/emacs-25.3-x86_64/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/org-9.1.6/lisp")
(add-to-list 'load-path "E:/Lisp/emacs-25.3-x86_64/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/org-9.1.6/contrib/lisp")
```

**Edit2:**

The other error I've seen:

```
(progn (load "e:\\Lisp\\slime-2.20\\swank-loader.lisp" :verbose t) (funcall (read-from-string "swank-loader:init")) (funcall (read-from-string "swank:start-server") "c:\\Users\\<user>\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\slime.14540"))

> Error: There is no package named "EXT" .
> While executing: CCL::%PARSE-TOKEN, in process listener(1).
> Type :GO to continue, :POP to abort, :R for a list of available restarts.
> If continued: Retry finding package with name "EXT".
> Type :? for other options.
1 > ;Loading #P"e:/Lisp/slime-2.20/swank-loader.lisp"...
;; Swank started at port: 60536.
60536
```

Comment: Is there a more extensive backtrace when you get the error? If so, add it to your question. Also try `M-x locate-library RET org RET` - if that gives you an error, then check that your load-path knows how to get to org (I note that you augment your load-path for slime, but not for org: are you using the built-in org mode - and what version of emacs are you running?)

Comment: @nick: Thanks very much, you pointed me in the right direction by suggesting to add the load-paths. I didn't know exactly how to identify which load-paths to add, but found it by googling. Would you like to convert your comment to an answer?

Comment: When using the built-in org, you should not have to do anything with the load-path to load org. So there is still a problem, but I'm not sure where that problem is.

Comment: The paths that you add are not canonical AFAIK. The built-in org mode should be under `/usr/share/emacs/25.3/lisp/org` on linux - I expect it's slightly different on Windows but not *that* different. Also the built-in org version on 25.3.3 on my Fedora 27 box is 8.2.10 and you are running 9.1.6. So it seems you are installing org-mode in some other way (maybe an Elpa/Melpa package?).

Comment: @Nick: I have changed the way I start Emacs since I initially installed it. Before, I start emacs by clicking on an icon that points to the exe file. Now, I created a batch file with these lines:  `set HOME=E:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/
E:/Lisp/emacs-25.3-x86_64/bin/runemacs.exe` I have also added in my init file this line: `(setq default-directory "E:/Lisp/ccl-1.11-windows/quicklisp/local-projects/")`  . Those could be the reasons?

Comment: @nick, looking at my  inferior-lisp buffer, I can see another error. which I've added above.

Comment: Yes, indeed. It looks as if you are munging the install (unnecessarily IMO). I don't know anything about Windows emacs but it should not be necessary to go through such contortions to set it up. But somebody with Windows expertise will have to chime in on that. I have no idea what causes your inferior-lisp error - sorry.